# multi-device-hybrid apps template is not loading after installing CTP2

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am getting an error message when I try to create a new multi-device-hybrid app. The error message is that, this template attempted to load component assembly

```
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSTemplateWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'.
```

And my output error message is :

```
C:\Users\Rishi\Desktop\Winjs Files\WinJS ToDo Sample for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps\JavaScript\WinJSToDo\WinJSToDo.jsproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Users\Rishi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\Rishi\Desktop\Winjs Files\WinJS ToDo Sample for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps\JavaScript\WinJSToDo\WinJSToDo.jsproj
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered this, along with several other errors after a fresh install of CTP2. For me it seemed that the installation process did not create a few specific directories for some reason, or for some reason it installed them in the wrong directory.

My solution was to create a copy of the 'vs-mda' & 'vs-mda-targets' directories, to get the entire build process to work (see below).

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\uxbwjkun.gjn\packages*
==>
C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\

Once I had done this, I could open, and start building the new projects created by CTP2.

I did have a few other build errors relating to various node packages that were also missing, which I simply installed as I discovered them using 'npm install -g ' from the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you. This has solved my error. Now it is opening up a new project but when i compile, Its asking for nodejs path.               
"Path to NodeJs has not been specified. Please check that NodeJs has been installed and set the NodeJsDir environment variable before building."

Comment: NodeJS is installed by CTP2, I would just add it to your path (ie. /Program File(x86)/nodejs/) if it is not already there. You can test by just opening a cmd prompt, and trying to execute 'node' from any directory.

Comment: I already had NodeJs installed but i didnt uncheck it while installing CTP2. I have checked the path and yes it is there. Still getting the error.

Comment: I have solved the error. I created one NodeJsDir environmental path and its working fine now.