# vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets was not found

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Trying to simply create a new Cordova "Blank App" using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

I see the template, but when trying to open the blank app, I get:

> The imported project
>   "C:\Users\jeades.GC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
>   was not found.  Confirm the path in the Import declaration is correct,
>   and that the file exists on disk

[image]

Tried installing/reinstalling the Multi Device Hybrid apps tool and I get the same problem.  The "vs-mda-targets" folder does not exist inside of node modules which is what it's complaining about but I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?  I assumed that would have been created with the install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an issue that happens intermittently.  Manually copying the targets files as described in the post below will fix the problem.

[multi-device-hybrid apps template is not loading after installing CTP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302269/multi-device-hybrid-apps-template-is-not-loading-after-installing-ctp2)

Comment: Ok, I was able to figure it out based off that answer.  Of course, the folder he refers to in that answer obviously will be named something different for other people.  Also, for those of us who have tried to re-install multiple time, there are a bunch of vs-mda-targets and vs-mda folders to choose from when copying over to node_modules.  Thank you.